# Out of memory on a xxxxxx-byte allocation in android

Tags: java, android, file-upload, out-of-memory, byte

I'm sending a zip file to server as bytes by opening HTTPConection object's getOutputStream.

`DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())`;

Then I'm just writing my bytes which i got from fileInputStream  into dos object.

This works up to certain amount of data say 100 MB.

To Maximize my heap size i added this line in my manifest's application tag

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

And while running i checked maximum available heap for my app with help of this snippet :

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
 long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
 Log.v(TAG, "maxMemory:" + Long.toString(maxMemory));
```

I got *maxMemory:536870912* as result in log.Which is exactly 512 MB.

While uploading  207 MB file

First my log says like

*Grow heap (frag case) to 207.792MB for 202833064-byte allocation*

And then my heap doubling when i try to write the data into dos object with the data i read.

*Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 405666588-byte allocation*

There i got force close with Out of memory on a 405666588-byte allocation.

This is my complete code :

```
int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                System.gc();
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);// Here I'm getting Out of memory while uploading 200 MB
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Max memory doesn't mean you can allocate all available space becase it fragmented and not solid. So you should read small chunk from file and write it and then read small chunk again. And call dos.flush() to send data.

Comment: Yes i have called flush() at the end of communication. I'll add flush () in the loop and check the effect.

Comment: `flush()` inside `while()` didn't help either ! I got memory exception exactly  at `dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize)`. Just added `flush()` after `write()` but  locked at first write() call itself !

Comment: Do you meant to say minimize the byte array size by small chunk?

Comment: Instead of reading whole 200mb you should read let's say 1mb and then write 1mb and then flush()